# Shouldn't this merge be working?

Tags: array, merge

Can anyone help me work out why the following returns the error "The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes."?

```
{# CREATE ARRAY TO HOLD ALL OF TODAY'S EVENTS #}
{% set todaysEvents = [] %}

{# GET TODAY'S ONE-OFF EVENTS #}
{# RETURNS ENTRIES NICELY IF LOOPED THROUGH #}
{% set todaysOneOffEvents = craft.entries.section('events').eventDate('= '~today | date("Y-m-d")) %}

{# ADD TODAY'S ONE-OFF EVENTS TO TODAY'S EVENTS %}
{# THIS RETURNS MERGE ARRAY ERROR #}
{% set todaysEvents = todaysEvents|merge(todaysOneOffEvents) %}
```

Comment: Thanks to this I finally learned the difference between an ElementCriteriaModel an an array of entries. The magic happens within the `find()` function :) Thanks for the question, Clive!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `find()` to your ElementCriteriaModel, I think without that function you're not actually saving your entries as an array in your variable `todaysOneOffEvents` yet.

Here's what I [found in the Docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#fetching-the-elements):

> You don’t actually need to call `find()` yourself though: It will be called automatically as soon as the ElementCriteriaModel is treated like an array (that is, as soon as you check how many elements there are using the `|length` filter, or start looping through the elements with a `{% for %}` loop).

We learn that merging doesn't "treat it like an array", good to know.

Edit: You can't use the `length` filter to "convert" the content of the variable to an actual array. Removed that part from the answer.

Comment: That's the bunny. Cheers.